# me sale error al querer hacer la conexion laravel 5.6 con Postgres y me sale error

Tags: laravel-5, postgresql

archivo **.env**

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=p1  
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=123456tuyyo
```

archivo **config/database.php**

```
 'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'pgsql'),
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zk3It.png]

[[image: 2]][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: Me sale este error]

Comment: Es problema de los driver.

Comment: si lo se pero como lo resuelvo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que no tienes habilitada los `drives` o `dlls` lo que tienes que hacer es ir a la carpeta de donde esta instalada tu `php`, en mi caso esta en : `C:\xampp\php` donde existe un archivo llamado `php.ini`, lo abres con privilegios de administrador y te vas hasta la **linea 905**(aprox) donde esta la siguiente linea:

```
;extension=pdo_pgsql
```

una linea mas abajo **907** tiene una linea:

```
;extension=pgsql
```

Entonces lo único que tienes que hacer es quitar el punto y coma (;), que esta por delante de esas lineas y quedarían de la siguiente forma.

```
extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pgsql
```

y listo guardas los cambios y funcionara correctamente.

Comment: Muchas Gracias amigo :D.